# Which is better: Openssl, LibreSSL or BoringSSL when compiled with Nginx (ngx_http_ssl_module)?

Tags: nginx, openssl

I am confused which ssl library is more suitable for Nginx `ngx_http_ssl_module`: **Openssl**, **LibreSSL** or **BoringSSL**?

Answer (score 0):

From the [ngx_http_ssl_module docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html):

> This module requires the OpenSSL library.

So I don't think you have a choice on this one.

Answer (score -1):

It's a toss-up between LibreSSL and BoringSSL. They're both likely to be more secure than the mess that is OpenSSL. Google just made a huge move to BoringSSL, so it's ready for production. However, you'll find more articles and how-tos on nginx + LibreSSL. Lots of people have already done it, and there are good scripts on GitHub.

Note that none of these libraries are formally verified. And they're all written in C. From these two facts we know in advance that all three of them are insecure, and that there will be a regular stream of security vulnerabilities for years to come. But so far, LibreSSL has seen fewer vulns than OpenSSL. (I can't find similar data for BoringSSL.)

That basic state of insecurity will remain until C is replaced by a clean-sheet, secure low-level programming language (like Rust, but not as terrible as Rust).